# Turn off smooth scrolling in GTK3

Tags: gnome, gui, gtk3, scrolling, accessibility

On a default Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) installation, GTK3 applications (which include most of the default GUI applications) have smooth scrolling activated. How do I disable it?

For example, in Gedit, pressing <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> causes the text to scroll one pixel line at a time until it settles to its final position one page further up/down. The same behavior occurs in the file selection dialog box, in Nautilus, etc. How do I turn off smooth scrolling, i.e. how do I make the <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> keys show the previous/next page immediately?

Comment: I haven't seen the behaviour you're describing with gedit. Could you please try adding `gtk-primary-button-warps-slider=false` to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and see if the problem goes away? If you don't have such a file, the first line should be `[Settings]`.

Comment: @DKBose Makes no difference.

Comment: Of course it makes no difference. `gtk-primary-button-warps-slider` isn't directly related to scrolling. It is related to the behavior of scrollbars, which is unrelated to this question.

Comment: Also, do you log out and back in for setting to get reread ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy https://superuser.com/questions/927160/how-can-i-disable-slow-scrolling-in-gnome-apps is about the scroll bar behavior, what does this have to do with my question? Besides it's for a different version: on Ubuntu 16.04, Gedit uses gtk2, not gtk3.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy My bad, Gedit does use gtk3, it reads both `~/.gtkrc-2.0` and `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`. But the suggested settings have no effect (unsurprisingly).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` to contain the following lines:

```
[Settings]
gtk-enable-animations=0
```

If the file doesn't exist, create it. If the file already exists and already has a `[Settings]` section, add [`gtk-enable-animations=0`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-enable-animations) in this section.

Thanks to [DK Bose](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903160/turn-off-smooth-scrolling-in-gtk3/1062482?noredirect=1#comment1416472_903160) for suggesting `.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and to [pm-b](https://askubuntu.com/a/1062482) for suggesting the option name `enable-animations` (I was looking for “scroll”).

You don't need to reboot or to log out, but you do need to restart the application.

Comment: I believe this setting can be queried by running `gtk-query-settings gtk-enable-animations`.  On my system, regardless of what I do or do not put in `.config/gtk3.0/settings.ini` (tried al the combinations), the `gtk-enable-animations` setting changes along whenever I change `enable-animations` using `gsettings`. Any clue on what could be the cause?

Comment: @pm-b `apt-cache search gtk-query-settings` → no results. You _are_ using Ubuntu 16.04, right? Gnome has a tendency to change configuration methods all the time, so what works one version of Ubuntu might not work in another version.

Comment: Oh wait you're right. I'm on my other computer.

Comment: This does not disable smooth scrolling on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @clemisch Indeed :( Unfortunately this seems to change with every version of Gnome, and to get harder and harder each time. It makes me avoid most Gnome applications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply on this old issue. Do you have experience on this with GTK3 on Ubuntu 18.04? It annoys me so much, yet I haven't found any clue. I've asked on AskUbuntu myself (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132444/how-to-deactivate-kinetic-scrolling-on-touchpad-in-gtk3-applications) but wasn't really successful...

Comment: Configuration file adjustments are so much better than invocations of gsettings, dconf-editor, etc. as they also work when one does not use any GTK+-based desktop environment. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by disabling animations in the gnome shell. Disabling animations will disable all animations. This setting can be changed in many different ways. For the change to take effect in gedit, don't forget to restart gedit.

#### Using `gsettings` (command line)

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

---

#### Using `dconf-editor` (GUI)

From the start screen, navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/enable-animations`

and set it to `false`.

---

#### Using `gnome-tweak-tool` (GUI)

Open `gnome-tweaks`. In the appearance tab, set the following option to `false`: *animations*

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I'm still getting smooth scrolling in the gnome file opening dialog and in gedit.

Comment: Just to be sure... I assume you restarted the shell / did a logout-login after the change?

Comment: No, I didn't log out. I did make sure that there was no running gedit process, then ran gedit. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations` reports `false` but this doesn't seem to have any effect on gedit.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Gnome apps have made this MAJOR mess on Ubuntu 18.04. The correct setting depends on the Desktop environment you use. For Gnome 3.x it seems that the way to disable smooth scroll is to run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

which disables other animations as well.

If you're running MATE you have to use different key

```
gsettings set org.mate.interface gtk-enable-animations false
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to fix this issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049588/gedit-last-line-obscured-by-status-bar