# gedit last line obscured by status bar

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gedit, text-editor

When I maximize *gedit* the last line of the text editor is obscured by the status bar at the bottom of the screen. This occurs even if I scroll to the very bottom of the document.

Say the document is 200 lines long. I can scroll to the bottom and see line 199. Line 200 is covered by the status bar of *gedit*. How do I overcome this issue? If I de-maximize the window I am able to access the last line of the text file I'm working on.

Comment: Not sure about what your issue exactly is about. If your text file is long enough, obviously the status bar will "obscure" lines that extend below. You need to scroll to bring it into view. That would appear normal behaviour to me. You always can disable the status bar in the preferences.

Comment: I have the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04 gedit 3.28.1. The file I open has 68 lines. However, I can only scroll with the mouse so that line 64 is the last visible line. When I scroll down with the keyboard, the cursor disappears but no more lines become visible. Interestingly, when I minimize and maximize the window, scrolling will work as expected.

Comment: Similar issue: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/issues/42 (This may also be what you are experiencing, @atmelino) Solution is https://askubuntu.com/questions/903160/turn-off-smooth-scrolling-in-gtk3

Answer (score 5):

You are looking at an issue, a bug, in gedit.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a somewhat larger text file in gedit in a window that is not maximized
2. Move the cursor to the last line
3. Maximize the window

Expected behaviour: the window is maximized and one sees the current line (the last line) at the bottom.

Observed behavior: the last displayed line is a few lines above. One does not see the line with the cursor.

When you use the left/right arrow keys, the line stays out of sight, which indeed is confusing. However, as soon as you press a left/right arrow key, or start typing, the line pops into view.

If this issue is not known to the gedit developers, it may be worth reporting it, although allegedly, it is not a severe issue.

I cannot reproduce, however, where you appear to suggest that you never can reach the last line. There is a [bug reported at Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=826278) in 2016 where the user cannot see the very last line without adding a return to the last line, but I cannot reproduce that in current gedit 3.28.1 in Ubuntu 18.04.

**Update 2022-04-26** The bug is still there in Ubuntu 22.04, Gedit 41. The bug report in the mean time has been forwarded to https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/issues/42 without resolution. Is that why Gnome 42 moved to a different standard editor?

Comment: _"although allegedly, it is not a severe issue."_ - after wasting a substantial amount of time debugging a server application and trying to comprehend why on earth it would cut off last few lines of a generated JSON file, I dare to disagree.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04 and gedit 3.28.1. The last 4 lines are not visible in the first view of the document,  but when I minimize the window, I can scroll to the very last line, and when I then maximize the window, it works normally as expected.

Comment: I found out that you can also switch to another window and then back to gedit in order to make it reveal the last lines.

Comment: @StefanHamcke  Thanks, it works for me as opposed to zoom-out/zoom-in, which has no effect. Maybe you could post it as an answer.

Comment: If what you are seeing is caused by https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/issues/42 there would be a (permanent) workaround: https://askubuntu.com/questions/903160/turn-off-smooth-scrolling-in-gtk3

Answer (score 1):

I (as you all) have been suffering of this issue since days
but only today I have found an easy way to overcome this problem.

I remember it's still open upstream **[1]**.

The tweak is easy-peasy: **zoom-out** and **zoom-in**, that's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.

---

**[1]** https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/issues/42

Comment: Permanent workaround: https://askubuntu.com/questions/903160/turn-off-smooth-scrolling-in-gtk3