# How to deactivate kinetic scrolling on touchpad in GTK3 applications?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, gtk3, scrolling

I'd like to deactivate the "kinetic scrolling" behavior of the GTK3 applications in Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome 3 (e.g. evince, gedit). If I scroll with the touchpad and don't lift my fingers perfectly vertically, the content keeps on scrolling as if it had momentum.

**Is there a global GTK setting to deactivate the kinetic scrolling feature?**

I found a couple of posts related to this, but not specifically to deactivate kinetic scrolling. It was only about smooth scrolling (with PageUp/Down keys) or about *activating* kinetic scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change the behaviour in `Settings > Devices > Mouse & Touchpad`.

If you aren't using Unity, you might want to launch the settings via

```bsh
$ unity-control-center
```

If you don't see any suitable settings there you may want to remove `libinput` again and switch to `synaptics` again:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput libinput-tools
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

And then configure it via `synclient`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't see an option in `Mouse & Touchpad` (Ubuntu 18.04, Gnome3). And I'm very sure that it has nothing to do with the driver because kinetic scrolling is a distinct feature of GTK3. The driver probably has to support it, but deactivating kinetic scrolling via the driver seems unnecessary (albeit maybe the only possibility >:-( )

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has various bugs connected with libinput. Some of them are fixed in 18.10 but they weren't backported (yet). That's why it is often recommended simply switching from libinput to synaptics again. So maybe you want to give it a try. It could be that you can even configure it in the regular settings after switching the driver and rebooting. If things are worse, you can switch back anyway, so you have probably nothing to loose here.

Comment: That sounds fair. I think I will try it then.